# Intellij Android Project Gradle

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, android-sdk-2.3, intellij-17

I can't sync my fresh Android Gradle project in Intellij Ultimate.

```
Module: ':app' platform 'android-32' not found.
```

Under Tools > Android > SDK Manager Android API 32 is installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your computer is connected to the internet, install the android SDK and then make a "build project".

Comment: Build project doesn't work: "Unable to find Gradle tasks to build: [:]. Build mode: COMPILE_JAVA. Tests: All."

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).